# ruby class problem

Tags: ruby

I have the following ruby code:

```
class Mp
  def initialize

    Test.new.mytest
    Work.new.mywork
    ha
    address

  end

  def ha
    puts "message from ha"
  end

  def address

   a='see'

  end

end


class Test

  def mytest
    m=Mp.new
    puts "Message from test do you #{m.address}"
  end
end

class Work

  def mywork
    puts "message from work"
  end

end

Mp.new
```

This works fine except the part in def mytest where I'm trying to put out the m.address. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the reason it doesn't work has nothing to do with printing the address. It's one line before that:

`m = Mp.new` this creates a new `Mp` object. However inside `Mp`'s initialize method a new `Test` object is created and its `mytest` method is called. The `mytest` method then again creates a new Mp object and so on. In other words: `Test#mytest` and `Mp#initialize` are mutually and infinitely recursive.

Edit in response to your comment:

I'm not quite sure I understood the question. If you mean "How do I access the variable `a` which was set in the `address` method, after `address` has been called": you don't. `a` is a local variable that goes out of scope once the method has returned. If you want to set an instance variable use `@a = 'see'`. `@` denotes instance variables in ruby. If you want to be able to access that variable from outside the object, use `attr_accessor :a` to define accessor methods for `@a`.

An example:

```
class Mp
  attr_accessor :c

  def initialize
    initialize_variables
    puts @c
    puts @b # I can access @c and @b here because it's an instance variable
            # and I'm within the same object

    # puts a # This does not work because a is a local variable from the
             # initialize_variables method and no longer in scope
  end

  def initialize_variables
    a = "a"
    @b = "b"
    @c = "c"
    puts a  # I can access a here because I'm still inside the method
            # where a was defined
  end
end

m = Mp.new
# puts m.a
# puts m.b  # These don't work because there are no methods a or b

puts m.c  # This works because attr_accessor defined a method c which
          # returns the content of m's @c variable
```

Comment: I see, how then would I access the string a='see' in the def address ?

Comment: So in my Mp class if I have the def address and it has a='see' I can access a in the Test by using @a? Can you post a quick example? Thanks

Comment: @MAP: No. If you do `a = 'see'`, you can't access `a` at all, once the method returns. If you do `@a = 'see'`, you can access `@a`, but only within the same object - not from outside. If you do `@a = 'see'` in the method *and* `attr_accessor :a` in the class definition, you can access `@a` from outside by doing `my_mp_object.a`. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an infinite loop.  You create a new object of class `Mp`, which in turn creates a new object of class `Test` and then calls its `mytest` method, which in turn creates another object of class `Mp`, which in turn...